# Can anyone help me identifying the type of adjective in the following sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-position, predicate-adjectives, attributive-adjectives

"**He is a beautiful boy.**"

I know that if an adjective is used before the noun, it is known as *attributive*, but here *he* is a pronoun and the adjective is used after the verb *is*. It's a little confusing as to what should I call the adjective in use- **attributive** or **predicative**? Is there any other term?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if an adjective is attributive or predicative \[EFL context\]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175562/how-to-tell-if-an-adjective-is-attributive-or-predicative-efl-context)

Comment: Not really, they did mention 'gala' as an attributive adjective in - It was a gala party. But they didn't tell me how exactly. I'm disoriented due to the presence of pronoun here, not able to tell whether it is attributive or predicative and why though? Can you please tell me?

Comment: But the pronoun makes no difference, because the adjective is "attached" to the noun ("boy" here) and not to the pronoun. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for the clarification 

Comment: The simple answer is that "beautiful" modifies "boy" within the predicative NP "a beautiful boy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is attributive usage. "Boy" is the noun to which the adjective is applied; it's "beautiful boy", and the adjective is coming first.  If you said "the boy is beautiful" then it would be predicative.

Comment: The word the OP is searching for is 'modifier'. "Beautiful" modifies "boy" in the NP "a beautiful boy". The whole NP is, of course, predicative.